# Effect of adding 0xff on a bitwise operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am taking a C final in a few hours, and I am going over past exams trying to make sure I understand problems I previously missed.  I had the below question and I simply left it blank as I didn't know the answer and I moved on, and looking at it now I am not sure of what the answer would be... the question is;

```
signed short int c = 0xff00;
unsigned short int d, e;

c = c + '\xff';
d = c;
e = d >> 2;

printf("%4x, %4x, %4x\n",c,d,e);
```

We were asked to show what values would be printed?  It is the addition of 'xff' which is throwing me off.  I have solved similar problems in binary, but this hex representation is confusing me.

Could anyone explain to me what would happen here?

Comment: $ff$ in hex is $255$ in decimal. No idea if that is of any help, though, because I don't know C.

Answer (score 3):

`'\xff'` is equivalent to all `1` in binary or `-1` in `signed int`.

So initially `c = 0xff00`

```
c = c + '\xff'
```

In binary is

```
c = 1111 1111 0000 0000 + 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

Which yields `signed short int`

```
c = 1111 1110 1111 1111 (0xfeff)
```

`c` and `d` will be equal due to assignment but `e` is right shifted twice

```
e = 0011 1111 1011 1111 (0x3fbf)
```

I took the liberty to test this. In the code I added `short int f` assigned the value of `c - 1`.

```
unsigned short int c = 0xff00, f;
unsigned short int d, e;

f = c-1;
c = c + '\xff';
d = c;
e = (d >> 2);

printf("%4x, %4x, %4x, %4x\n",c,d,e,f);
```

And I get the same result for both `c` and `f`. `f = c - 1` is not buffer overflow. `c + '\xff'` isn't buffer overflow either

```
feff, feff, 3fbf, feff
```

As noted by [Zan Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13422/zan-lynx), I was using `unsigned short int` in my sample code but the original post is `signed short int`. With signed int the output will have 4 extra f's.

Comment: This is the case of integer overflow. Are you sure you are getting the same result as in your answer?

Comment: I tried this out and you're missing one tricky bit. The printf will actually convert c from short int to int, which means it'll print 8 'f's instead of just 4.

Comment: Your code sample isn't using a signed short like the code in the question.

Comment: When printf converts short int to int, the value is prepended with zeroes, not ones. Thus it will print 0x000ffff. You should try it.

Comment: @Zan Lynx - quick eyes. You are right. I've been using unsigned instead of the signed as originally posted.

Comment: Actually the C99 spec, section 6.4.4.4 paragraph 9 specifies that an octal or hex character escape shall produce a character that is in range for type **unsigned char**, which will then be converted to type int.  So `\xff` should be 255, not -1.

Answer (score 1):

`0xff00` means the binary string `1111 1111 0000 0000`.

`'\xff'` is a character with numeric code of `0xff` and thus simply `1111 1111`.

Comment: Note that on most modern compilers with signed 8-bit chars the '\xff' literal will get promoted and signed-extended to -1 in the expression. As will in all likelihood the 16-bit signed shorts when implicitly promoted in printf's variable argument list.

Comment: @doynax:  actually no -- The C99 spec has a special exemption for hex and octal character escapes, which always treats them explicitly as **unsigned** chars -- see 6.4.4.4.9

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I never knew that, thought it makes sense given the similar exception for unsigned promotion of hexadecimal/octal integer constants. I have to say it's a rather subtle breaking change from C89 where sign-extension is mandated ("In an implementation in which type char has the same range of values as signed char, the integer character constant '\xFF' has the value -1") and apparently an insidious expression to put into a schoolwork exercise

Answer (score 1):

```
signed short int c = 0xff00;
```

is initializing `c` with out of range value (`0xff00 = 65280 in decimal)`. This will cause to produce an erroneous result.

Comment: You may need to add some explanation so the OP will understand how the Hex translates to the binary.

Comment: Actually, this is not an overflow -- its initializing a variable with an out of range value.  So the result (per 6.3.1.3.3 of the C99 spec) is either an **implementation defined** value or an **implementation defined** signal, and NOT undefined behavior -- a conforming implementation must document what it does and do it consistently.  A subtle and sometimes important distinction.

Comment: @ChrisDodd; Thanks for specification reference.

Answer (score 1):

The first addition adds the 16-bit number, stored in `c`:
`1111 1111 0000 0000`

Plus the number that is coded as the value of the ASCII char enclosed between ' '. But in C you can specify a character as an hexadecimal code prefixed by `\x` like this `'\xNN'` where `NN` is a two hex digit number. The ASCII code of that character is the value of `NN` itself. So `'\xFF'` is a somewhat unusual way to say `0xFF`.

The addition is to be performed using a `signed short` (16 bits, signed) plus a `char` (8 bits, signed). For it, the compiler  promotes that 8-bit value to a 16-bit value, preserving the original sign by doing a sign-extension conversion.

So before the addition, `'xFF'` is decoded as the 8-bit signed number `0xFF` `(1111 1111)`, which in turn is promoted to the 16-bit number `1111 1111 1111 1111` (the sign must be preserved)

The final addition is

```
1111 1111 0000 0000
1111 1111 1111 1111
-------------------
1111 1110 1111 1111
```

Which is the hexadecimal number `0xFEFF`. That is the new value in variable `c`.

Then, there is `d=c;` `d`is `unsigned short`: it has the same size of a `signed short`, but sign is not considered here; the MSb is just another bit. As both variables have the same size, the value in `d` is exactly the same we had in `c`. That is:

```
d = 1111 1110 1111 1111
```

The difference is that any aritmetic or logical operation with this number won't take sign into account. This means, for example, that conversions that change the size of the number won't extend the sign.

```
e = d >> 2;
```

`e` gets the value of `d` shifted two bits to the right. The `>>` operator behaves differently depending upon the left operand is signed or not. If it is signed, the shifting is performed preserving the sign (bits entering the number from the left will have the same value as the original sign the number had before the shifting). If it is not, there will be zeroes entering from the left.

`d` is unsigned, so the value `e` gets is the result of shifting `d` two bits to the right, entering zeroes from the left:

```
e = 0011 1111 1011 1111
```

Which is `0x3FBF`.

Finally, values printed are `c,d,e`:

`0xFEFF, 0xFEFF, 0x3FBF`

But you may see `0xFFFFFEFF` as the first printed number. This is because `%x` expects an `int`, not a `short`. The `4` in `"%4x"` means: *"use at least 4 digits to print the number, but if the amount of digits needed is more, use as much as needed"*. To print `0xFEFF` as an `int` (32-bit int actually), it must be promoted again, and as it's signed, this is done with sign-extension. So `0xFEFF` becomes `0xFFFFFEFF`, which needs 8 digits to be printed, so it does.

The second and third `%4x` print unsigned values (`d` and `e`). These values are promoted to 32-bit ints, but this time, unsigned. So the second value is promoted to `0x0000FEFF` and the third one, to `0x00003FBF`. These two numbers don't actually need 8 digits to be printed, but 4, so it does so and you see only 4 digits for each number (try changing the two last `%4x` by `%2x` and you will see that the numbers are still printed with 4 digits)